# Trying to Fill a DropDown in a GridView in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to fill a `ComboBox` that is on a `GridView`

Something like this

[image]

the `DropDown` that show something is because I Fill it manually.

This is the code that I'm using to try to fill the `DropDown`

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList Gv_tool = (e.Row.FindControl("Gv_tool") as DropDownList);

        DataTable rdvt = RESBTable.regconnect();

        this.Dpo_tool.DataSource = rdvt;

        Gv_tool.DataSource = rdvt;
        Gv_tool.DataTextField = "tool_id";
        Gv_tool.DataValueField = "tool_id";
        Gv_tool.DataBind();
        Gv_tool.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Herramienta", String.Empty));

    }
}
```

when I'm trying to go to the page this crashes andtold me this:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Error pin-point:

[image]

This is my TemplateField on HTML:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tool">
       <EditItemTemplate>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="Gv_tool" runat="server">
           </asp:DropDownList>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tool_id") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
           <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Looks like your image link has gone bad. Please fix it.

Comment: I'm trying but doesn't fix it

Comment: still, which exact line throws this error inside your if block? Can you pin-point a bit?

Comment: I fix the images

Comment: I believe the dropdownlist control present in designer view of html doesn't have the `id` as `Gv_tool`. Please check it in html designer of your aspx page.

Comment: You should comment your code where the error happens for the sake of people who can't see images. This likely comes back null at this time. `DropDownList Gv_tool = (e.Row.FindControl("Gv_tool") as DropDownList);`

Comment: @RBT actually it has an `Id`

Comment: @blaze_125 I'm sorry, my fault, the error marks on `Gv_tool.DataSource = rdvt;`

Comment: Whait a sec! I fix it seeing another problem just like mine I just have a question aboit it whith the two last rows, I just update the post

Comment: Then leave your opening post as a problem, and post and accept your own solution. Your findings, worded your way may help others down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gv_tool (dropdown) is in EditItemTemplate. so you need bind it when row editing.

change

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
```

to

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex == GridView1.EditIndex)
```

Comment: Yes, I Actually fix it and update the post with the solution! but thaks a lot for taking your time! actually can you explain me what are they for the last two rows in the code?

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos It is not good to update the question itself with the final solution else how would the future readers seeing your post will get to know the original problem. I would recommend that you revert the source code in your question post to the initial one where you were facing the run-time exception. Also please accept this post as a correct solution (by clicking the grey check mark below voting buttons) if it helped you go past the error.

Comment: @RBT i'm sorry I try to revert but i didn't have the code :/ I'll never going to do that again

Comment: No worries. I've fixed it for now. You can always go into the edit history of any post to look for older state/content of any post.